# Using Boost Python with shared_ptr<const T>

Tags: python, c++, boost, constants, shared-ptr

Boost Python 1.63 (python 2.7.13) works well with `shared_ptr<T>`; if I write this in C++:

```
shared_ptr<Foo> create_shared_ptr() { return shared_ptr{...}; }
void accept_shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Foo>& p) { }

...

class_<Foo, boost::noncopyable>("Foo", no_init); //Expose abstract class

register_ptr_to_python< shared_ptr<Foo> >();
def("create_shared_ptr", create_shared_ptr);
def("accept_shared_ptr", accept_shared_ptr);
```

Then I can write this in Python and everything works:

```
accept_shared_ptr(create_shared_ptr())
```

**The problem comes when I try and wrap `shared_ptr<const Foo>`.** (Which I need to do because I am wrapping a library that returns this.) If I modify the C++ functions as follows:

```
shared_ptr<const Foo> create_shared_ptr() { return shared_ptr{...}; }
void accept_shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<const Foo>& p) { }
```

Then I get the error:

> ```
> Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
>     mod_python.accept_shared_ptr(Foo)
> did not match C++ signature:
>     accept_shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<Foo const>)
> ```

It seems the internals are implementing conversion from python `Foo` to C++ `shared_ptr<Foo>`, but not to C++ `shared_ptr<const Foo>`. Using

```
register_ptr_to_python< shared_ptr<const Foo> >();
```

doesn't help. How can I fix this?

Comment: To whoever voted to close: the answer below based on boost 1.62 does not fix the issue. There is a commit `Add support for std::shared_ptr.` on Sep 23, 2016.  Boost 1.62 was released on Sep 1, and 1.62 on Nov 2. (https://github.com/boostorg/python/commit/97e4b34a15978ca9d7c296da2de89b78bba4e0d5). It's possible this commit broke something.

Comment: Please include namespaces, it's unclear if you're using std::shared_ptr or boost_shared_ptr

Answer (score 2):

The issue must be in the definitions of your classes/methods. This code works for me (I have boost 1.62 and python 2.7.13):

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    virtual std::string xxx() = 0;
};

class Bar: public Foo {
public:
    ~Bar() override = default;
    std::string xxx() override { return "xxx"; }
};

std::shared_ptr<const Foo> create_shared_ptr() {
    return std::shared_ptr<const Foo>(new Bar);
}

void accept_shared_ptr(const std::shared_ptr<const Foo>& p) 
{
    ; // do nothing
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(myLib)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<Foo, boost::noncopyable>("Foo", no_init);
    register_ptr_to_python< std::shared_ptr<const Foo> >();
    def("create_shared_ptr", create_shared_ptr);
    def("accept_shared_ptr", accept_shared_ptr);
}
```

Then, in python I can do:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import myLib
>>> ptr = myLib.create_shared_ptr()
>>> ptr
<myLib.Foo object at 0x7f8b5fde0aa0>
>>> myLib.accept_shared_ptr(ptr)
```

Most probably your function `create_shared_ptr` somehow returns a wrong value that is misunderstood by python.

Comment: Interesting. Your C++ code generates the same error for me:

    ```Python argument types in
        myLib.accept_shared_ptr(Foo)
did not match C++ signature:
    accept_shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<Foo const>)```

Comment: COuld i ask what compiler you are using? I'm using g++ 6.4 and compiling with `-std=c++11`. Also are you including any headers that might allow more conversions?

Comment: `g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18) 6.3.0 20170516`, `-std=c++1y` (I know, it should be c++14), `cmake version 3.7.2`. From boost included just `#include <boost/python.hpp>`, but actually I embedded the sample code in my other project that includes OpenCV dependencies. I see that problem is solved - good (even if maybe a little bit hacky).

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
implicitly_convertible<std::shared_ptr<Foo>,std::shared_ptr<const Foo>>();
```

solves the problem.